# How to reduce the size html file crated by folium

Tags: python, geospatial, folium

I am trying to plot a map using folium; the total rows are 1.2 million. The size of the folium map generated is about 590 MB. Is there some way I can reduce the size of the same

Tried using the slimmer package but it does not support map objects

Comment: what have you tried so far ?   please post the code...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example